# PHP Get Hidden Variable from an AJAX Image Uploader

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

I am using [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/) AJAX Image Uploader script and what I am trying to do is pass a hidden variable.

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
```

But since there is no real submit button, it is all AJAX based, I cannot just call `$_POST['test']`;

Part of the jQuery is:

```
if (formdata) {  
    $.ajax({  
        url: "upload.php",  
        type: "POST",  
        data: formdata,  
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,  
        success: function (res) {  
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;  
        }  
    });  
}
```

It should probably go somewhere in there but I'm not sure on how to approach this. If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
Just give your hidden input an id so we can refer to it and get the value. I used `hidden_input` in this case.

```
if (formdata) { 
    //New line is below!
    formdata.append("test",$('#hidden_input').val());
    $.ajax({  
        url: "upload.php",  
        type: "POST",  
        data: formdata,  
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,  
        success: function (res) {  
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Then your `upload.php` should be able to access the value with `$_POST['test']`

Answer (score 3):

> But since there is no real submit button, it is all AJAX based, I cannot just call $_POST['test'];

Sure you can. AJAX can send any header you want in the `type` parameter. If you put `type:'post'` just as you have it now, the field with `name="test"` will be available via `$_POST['test']`

You can have any event trigger the ajax, including the page load.

```
$('somenode').bind('someevent',function(){
```

So, say you want the ajax to post every time a field value is changed:

```
$('input').change(function(){
    $.ajax({  
        url: "upload.php",  
        type: "POST",  
        data: formdata,  
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,  
        success: function (res) {  
            $('#response').html(res);  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all. The question is asking how to send additional values via POST to a php script.

Comment: Not sure how you got that out of his question, but good work nonetheless :)

Comment: I apologize if the question wasn't too clear. Thanks for your help though!